# data matching/data selection with multiple conditions in a long shaped database r

Tags: r, dataset, selection

I have been struggling with this problem for a while, it's a rather complex data selection with multiple possible output and I can't find the expression to get what I want.
I am measuring divorce rates in a colony of birds.

reproducible database:

```
nest<- rep(seq(1:10),2)
year<- c(rep(2014, 10), rep(2015, 10))
pair<- c("TH4327_TH4317", "2", "TH8522_T75390" ,"4", "TJ1704_TJ1703", "TH4335_TH4333",
         "7", "8", "TH4337_TH4323", "T74703_TH1797",
         "TH4327_TH4317", "12", "TH8522_T75550","14", "TJ1704_NA" , "TH4335_TH4333",           "17", "TH8715_TH8714", "TH4388_TH4323", "TE9639_TH9675")
test<- data.frame(nest, year, pair)
test$pair <- as.character(test$pair)
test$year <- as.character(test$year)
```

The underscore separates the ID of 2 members of a pair. When no ID is present a growing number is placed. The same nests for each year are displayed.
In the 2 consecutive years we have 5 possible scenarios (the numbers are the nest IDs):

> SAME PAIR 2014-2015: 1-6
>
> EMPTY 2014-2015: 2-4-7
>
> EMPTY 2014 but OCCUPIED 2015: 8
>
> CHANGE OF PAIRS IN THE SAME NEST: 10
>
> CHANGE OF ONE OF THE MEMBER OF THE PAIR: 3-9
>
> UNKNOWN: 5

The results that I am after are:

pairs that stayed together "SAME PAIR 2014-2015" : 2
pairs in which one changed "CHANGE OF ONE OF THE MEMBER OF THE PAIR": 2

I figured how to calculate the pairs that stay together...

```
same<-test$pair[test$year=="2014"] %in% test$pair[test$year=="2015"]
table(same)
```

However I cannot obtain information about pairs which divorce.

I tried several commands, `which` and `ifelse`, but have not been successful.

I am happy to give further explanation if something is not clear. I know is quite a messy problem.

Thanks a lot,
all the best.

have fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using merge. The strategy is as follows.  First split the pairs into `p1` and `p2` (I did this with `tidyr::separate`).  Then I subset the data across years and merge using `p1` as an unique identifier.  This means that there will now be two different `p2`, one for 2014 and one for 2015.  It is now straightforward to test if groups stay together or divorce.

If you have many years, this approach will need to be generalized.  I would gladly provide such a generalization if need be.

```
library(tidyr)

test <- 
test %>%
  filter(nchar(test$pair) > 3) %>% #getting rid of missing pairs
  separate(pair, c("p1", "p2"), "_") %>%
  select(-nest) #getting rid of nest which is superfluous 

test <- merge(test[test$year=="2014",], test[test$year=="2015",], by = "p1", all = TRUE)

#Same group across 2014 and 2015
na.omit(test[test$p2.x == test$p2.y, grep("p", names(test))])

#Different Group across 2014 and 2015
na.omit(test[test$p2.x != test$p2.y, grep("p", names(test))])
```

#### Update

To generalize the code for many years use the following code.  It is a much better approach than looping.  Also note that the above code did not work because I forgot to include the `dplyr` library.  Be sure to download and load both `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  These libraries are great for data manipulation.  Here are some sources on [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) and [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).  Let me know if you have any more problems.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

test <- 
test %>%
  filter(nchar(test$pair) > 3) %>% #getting rid of missing pairs
  separate(pair, c("p1", "p2"), "_") %>% #splitting pairs
  select(-nest) #getting rid of nest which is superfluous 

test <- split(test, test$year) #split data into lists by year
test <- Map(function(d, n){names(d)[grepl("p2", names(d))] <- paste("p2", n, sep = "_"); d}, d = test, n = names(test)) #this line can be omitted.  It simply insures that your final data set looks nice.
test <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "p1", all = TRUE), test)
```

#### Without Packages (i.e. in Base R)

If you don't want to use the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages you can replace the first several lines of code (up until when `split` is called) with this base R approach

```
test <- test[nchar(test$pair) > 3, !names(test)%in%"nest"]

split_pair <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(test$pair, "_"))

test$p1 <- split_pair[, 1]
test$p2 <- split_pair[, 2]
test <- test[, !names(test)%in%"pair"]
```

#### Final Update... hopefully

have fun brings up a great point in the comment below.  Since I use `p1` as a unique identifier, it is not possible to identify when `p2` changes.  To overcome this I do the following...

```
 test <- split(test, test$year) #split data into lists by year

 test <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("p1", "p2"), all = TRUE), test) #merge on both p1 and p2 to overcome the previous problem.  Pair are now unique identifiers

#Stayed in same relationship
stay = test$year.x == "2014" & test$year.y == "2015"
na.omit(test[stay, ])

#p1 changes couples between year.x and year.y
tp1 <- test[test$p1 %in% test[duplicated(test$p1), "p1"], c("p1", "p2", "year.x", "year.y")]
is_na <- (is.na(tp1$year.x) & is.na(tp1$year.y))
stay_tp1 <- tp1$year.x == "2014" & tp1$year.y == "2015"
stay_tp1[is.na(stay_tp1)] <- FALSE
tp1 <- tp1[!(stay_tp1 | is_na), ]

#A similar approach works for p2.  Notice it is probably best to do this in a function.  If you do use a function remember you will need to pass your variables as strings, unless you want to use NSE.
```

The final bit of code might be a bit confusing.  Let me explain.  To identify if a bird changes partners we identify duplicates, since a bird that moves from one pair to another will appear twice.  In the case of many years, however, bird can change pairs in any one of several years.  To identify the correct year which the bird changes you need to use the above code.  I suggest that you construct a function to deal with this case, since there is a fair bit of typing involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Jacob. I understand your strategy however I dunno the package. When I try to run the scripts it gives me an error: `no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class ...` . And yes...I do have many years, I think I will just for loop through them or do you have another better strategy to generalize....

Comment: @havefun I updated. It may be the case that the code did not work because you also need to load the `dplyr` library.

Comment: I finally really understood your script, however there is one complication that your solution doesn't deal with, it's not always the second identifier that changes, there is one case, the ninth in the example, in which is the first identifier that changes. This case is not detected (In fact I am not interested in the one that have the NA either). Do you suggest to just run the same script twice putting `p2` as unique identifier and then summing up the results or there is a better solution? Thanks again, I am learning a lot from your strategies!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fixed code, now the problem is solved. However I cannot generalize the code for my database because too long (over 5000 rows) so the line `test <- split(test, test$year)` create a "large list" and  when I run  `test <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("p1", "p2"), all = TRUE), test)` it gives me an error "I cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 gb"